# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener() called multiple times

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and my problem is that chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener() is being called multiple times.

My code is like this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.status == 'complete' && tab.url != undefined){
         doSomething
    }
});
```

This is related to Chrome Issue 162543 and it appears as fixed but I still have this problem.

Comment: Is the event listener getting run multiple times or are there multiple events triggering?

Comment: Can you post your manifest.json file? If you have "persistent": false in your background entry, you can get multiple calls on the onUpdated event.

Answer (score 9):

Please be aware `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` will also fired for iframes, if a page contains many iframes, each completed iframe will trigger the event though you have checked `changeInfo.status`.

To solve this issue, you could take a look at my answer in this post [Chrome extension - page update twice then removed on YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808309/chrome-extension-page-update-twice-then-removed-on-youtube/36818991#36818991), and use `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` or `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated`, which depends on your testing sites.