# Chrome and closing a specific tab URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to close a specific tab in Google Chrome.
The behaviour is that an extension open up URL after she loaded and this can't be avoid.

This doesn't work :

```
#manifest.json
 {
    "name": "Close Tab Helpx Adobe",
    "description": "Close the url http://www.example.com",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"],
            "persistent": false
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "close-tab-helpx-adobe-16.png",
        "128": "close-tab-helpx-adobe-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
 }

#background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) {
        if(tab.url=="http://www.example.com") {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab)
        }
});
```

In developper mode, i can see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined`

As you can see, i'm a beginner.
Do you know how to achieve this ?

EDIT:
I also tried :

```
#background.js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
        if(tab.url=="http://www.example.com") {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab);
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
    if(tab.url=="http://www.example.com") {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab);
    }
});
```

---

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    if(tabs[0].url=="http://www.example.com") {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0]);
    }
});
```

The error is the same, only the property name change `onActivated`, `getcurrent` or `query`

Comment: Without seeing manifest.json I can only guess you're trying to do it in a content script, which you can't. This API must be used in a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). Also always refer to the documentation of each event and method: your parameters for both onUpdated listener and remove() method are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, before asking i tried a lot of method. In my case, thoses lines come from background.js (i've just follow the chrome documentation and my searches give me some clues to write those lines). It seems that i need to search more, sorry for asking...

Comment: I guess manifest.json's `"permissions"` list doesn't have `"tabs"`?

Comment: Nice try. Wrong guess ^^. I've just edit the post with manifest.json...
Thank you for your advices.

Comment: You have a Chrome app, not an extension. Apps can't use API for extensions. If you did it by accident then remove `"app"` section and declare a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) instead.

Comment: The app section is removed from the manifest and there is no more error. Instead, nothing happens ^^
Thanks for your help @wOxxOm
I have now to figure out why it doesn't work...

Comment: chrome.tabs.remove accepts an id or an array of ids, not a tab object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) (and his patience), here is a code which do the job :

```
#manifest.json
 {
    "name": "Close Tab Helpx Adobe",
    "description": "Close the url http://www.example.com",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"],
            "persistent": false
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "close-tab-helpx-adobe-16.png",
        "128": "close-tab-helpx-adobe-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
 }

#background.js
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                if(tab.url=="http://www.example.com") {
                    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
                }
        });
    });
```

So, i have my answer.

To go further ...

> [Haibara Ai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741762/haibara-ai) says *"Please be aware chrome.tabs.onUpdated will also fired for iframes, if a page contains many iframes, each completed iframe will trigger the event though you have checked : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36818991/2241806"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36818991/2241806%22)*

Comment: How do we use this codes/